# Nginx - Redirect homepage if cookie set

Tags: redirect, nginx, cookies

I need to redirect the homepage to a subpage but only if a specific cookie is set. I tried the following:

```
location = / {
  if ($http_cookie ~* "cookiename=cookievalue") {
    return 301 /subpage;
  }
  if ($http_cookie ~* "cookiename2=cookievalue2") {
    return 301 /subpage2;
  }
}
```

But that results in a 403 Forbidden Error on the Homepage if the cookie is set or not. I also can't put the location inside the if, which is apparently not allowed.

Comment: What action should it take if neither `if` statement matches? You may need to add another `return` statement. Also, 301 means permanent - perhaps 302 would be more appropriate.

Comment: When no if matches the normal homepage should load, so just "/". I will change 301 to 302. But how does the default return need to look like?

Comment: You have overridden the normal homepage - look at (maybe) your `location /` block which will contain the code necessary to process the normal homepage.

Comment: There is no other location / block within this nginx configuration.

Comment: If there is no other `location /` block, then what is the `location` block that normally serves your home page?  This question might be easier to answer if you are able to post the entire config file.